# typescript unable to add definition files to webstorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, file-watcher

i want to use baconjs with TS,but after copy baconjs def file for ts,i got that msg:
bacon.ts(216,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

to solve that,i should add a file watcher with --module cmd for tsc,but i cannot find how to distinguish between module and other ts files from file watcher settingsff

news:
after add d.ts file,there are lots of errors like that
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after add d.ts file,there are lots of errors like that

Thats because Webstorm isn't updated to TS 1.4 which introduced promises. Fix: Use an older `.d.ts` (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/1.3.0) or wait for webstorm to update.

Comment: Thanks,now i just ignore the errors...just let it compile

Answer (score 3):

I find WebStorm's TypeScript implementation strange.

It seems WebStorm needs to know about the .d.ts -- and right now the only way to do that is go to:

`WebStorm > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Libraries`

Then click the `Download` button. Select the dropdown at the top that defaults to `Official libraries` and select `TypeScript community stubs`. Then select a definition you would like to use.

This seems very redundant. Most projects use `tsd` to manage definition dependancies. I hope someone here tells us there is an easier way to do this with WebStorm.

Comment: for jquery,i download a d.ts file,but abundant of errors appeared in the d.ts file..also tried visual studio ,it's ok but do not want to switch..

Comment: Right, WebStorm seems to not want you to manually download the d.ts, but use the long procedure in my answer.

Comment: I'd like to recommend https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript (I am a collaborator)